# Remove a tablerow in an Ajax callback, but Ajax won't get past readyState 1

Tags: javascript, ajax, readystate

I'm trying to remove a tablerow. 
It seems that it only gets to **readyState 1**

Here it is:

```
var element = $('table:nth-child(5)>tbody>tr:nth-child(5)');
   $.ajax({
     success: function(){          
        element.remove();     
   }
});
```

Comment: What is your issue? Ready State 1 is success. Is `success` triggered? If so does the removal of the element work? If not, what error do you see in the browser console? What are you asking?

Comment: yes success is triggered. The removal disappear after refreshing the website. I want to remove the table permanently.

Answer (score -1):

In the 'readystate' success method, the element will not be defined. Define the same in the success as shown below.

```
$.ajax({
     success: function(){   
        var element = $('table:nth-child(5)>tbody>tr:nth-child(5)');       
        element.remove();     
   }
   });
```